# How to style conversations like Facebook private messages

Tags: css

I'm setting up private conversations between users on a site. I like Facebook private messages UI and plan to implement it similarly.

I'm having a hard time trying to implement this due that it uses different css positions in order to align elements on screen correctly. Here is my problem summarized.

[image]

1. The width should be the 100% of the width available where it is placed. Thats mostly auto.
2. The height should go from the current point until the end of the page. If I use `position: fixed` I lost somehow the auto width of point (1) and need to set it manually.
3. This is the most tricky. How can I position the write message at bottom and yet get messages to have an auto height inside its container based on its container height and write message presence?

Comment: elements with `position: fixed;` are removed from the flow, therefor your described behavior in point 2 is just normal. I don't know it exactly, but the overflow-property might help you with point 3 regarding the message container.